# How do I fix "unexpected token 'export'" error when I try to use uuid package?

Tags: node.js, backend, require, uuid

I'm working in a vue.js application with node.js in the backend. We've installed the npm package uuid in the backend but it's not working.

Our package.json file in the backend contains this:

```
"uuid": "^8.2.0",
```

In our controller, in the constructor, we have this:

```
this.uuid = require("uuid");
```

And we use it like this:

```
const id = this.uuid.v1();
```

The problem is, when we call the endpoint on the backend, we get this error:

```
C:\...\backend\node_modules\uuid\dist\esm-browser\index.js:1
export { default as v1 } from './v1.js';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Googling this issue, the only solutions I've found involve importing v1 specifically, such as this:

```
import {v1 as uuid} from "uuid";
```

But since we're using node.js on the backend, we get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried module.exports?

Comment: I faced this issue when I upgraded @google-cloud/logging module to latest version 8.1.0. Error is gone when rolled bak to v6.0.0.

Comment: Might be a little late but I had the same issue running Node.js 13, updating my package.json to use 14.1.0 fixed the issue, I read downgrading to 12 can also help to use the commonjs version of uuid by default. (14 uses esmodule).

Comment: Downgrading to 12 fixed it for me.  Windows 7 forced be user v12

Answer (score 0):

I have been there. Used this approach:

```
const uuid = require('uuid');
const newUuid = uuid.v4();
```

You may use `.v1()` instead of `.v4()`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. The issue is that uuid.v1() results in the error above.

Answer (score 0):

You should first export your functions (that you need in other modules) in v1.js like below-

```
function xyz() {
}

module.exports = xyz;
```

You can then use this in the respective files as-

```
const xyz = require(‘../pathname’);
```

Comment: So I tried replacing "export default v1" with "module.exports = v1" in v1.js, and then using "require('uuid/v1')" but it didn't work.